# WPF control reference from xaml is not visible on the code side

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="EffectsContext"
                Name="EffectsMenu"
                StaysOpen="true">

    <MenuItem Header="Add Blur">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Width="16"
                    Height="16"
                    Source="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Resources.BlurIcon},
                                    Converter={StaticResource BitmapToImageSourceConverter}}" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem Header="Add Fractal">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Width="16"
                    Height="16"
                    Source="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Resources.Fractalcon},
                                    Converter={StaticResource BitmapToImageSourceConverter}}" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

`EffectsMenu` isn't accessable in my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file. When I try it, it complains that it's not accessible in the current context:

```
public MainWindow ( )
{
    this.InitializeComponent ( );

    Console.WriteLine ( EffectsMenu );
}
```

I also tried:

```
x:Name="EffectsMenu"
```

but same result.

Any ideas what might be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: And where is this menu defined? In a Resources section? Resources have Keys, not Names.

Comment: Yes It's inside the TreeView control's resources. So should I put it somewhere else and make it accessible to both?

Comment: But, why would you like to access the control from the code behind? Maybe there is a better way to achieve what you REALLY neeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
 var v = FindResource("EffectsContext");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you added an x:key="" i think that you declared the ContextMenu in a ResourceDictionary(like `<SomeControl.Resources>`). In this case you can't access it directly, try the following:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
  <StackPanel x:Name="sp">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
      <ContextMenu x:Key="EffectsContext"
                   Name="EffectsMenu"
                   StaysOpen="true">

      </ContextMenu>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```cs
ContextMenu menu = this.sp.Resources["EffectsContext"] as ContextMenu;
```

Comment: Thanks, I had this code, but got a crash so thought of trying to access the control directly, instead of this searching and casting. But if it's not possible, then I will use it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `x:Key` on the `ContextMenu`

Answer (score 0):

should that x:Key be x:Name instead?

Comment: I use the Key in the xaml side, but I changed the Name to x:Name, but same error.

Answer (score -2):

Can't test here, just a guess:

```
this.EffectsMenu
```