# How to access menuitem in a ContextMenu that is part of a resources

Tags: wpf, resources, contextmenu, menuitem

I am trying to access the MenuItem in a ContextMenu which itself is part of a countrol's resources

```
                    <TreeView.Resources>
                        <ContextMenu x:Key ="GroupContext"  StaysOpen="true">
                        <MenuItem Header="Blast to Whole Group" Click="BlastGroup_Click"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu x:Key ="ContactContext"  Style="{x:Null}" Loaded="ContextMenu_Loaded">
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete Contact" Click ="ContactDelete_Click"/>
                            <MenuItem x:Name="ModifyGroupMenuItem" Header="Modify Grouping"  Style="{x:Null}">
                            </MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                </TreeView.Resources>
```

How can I get a hold of ModifyGroupMenuItem?
I found a solution to get hold of the ContextMenu [WPF control reference from xaml is not visible on the code side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997487/wpf-control-reference-from-xaml-is-not-visible-on-the-code-side)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By an index into the Items collection, or by looking through the logical tree.

```
    ContextMenu menu = this.Resources["ContactContext"] as ContextMenu;

    MenuItem menuitemindex0 = menu.Items[0] as MenuItem;
    MenuItem menuitemindex1 = menu.Items[1] as MenuItem;

    MenuItem menuitembyname = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(menu, "ModifyGroupMenuItem") as MenuItem;
```